# How can I convert this from jQuery to vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, hover

For everything else I am working on right now I have converted from jQuery to vanilla just fine, however I am wondering about how I could do the following with vanilla JS.

I am wanting to set a hover event on an array of objects. In the event handler function I want to change some css properties on some child elements. The trick is I want to select these child elements by class, but make sure to only select the child elements from the element that triggered the hover event handler.

So I need to replace .hover() .find() and .css() with vanilla JS.

```
$('.item').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.qLeft > img').css('box-shadow', '2px 2px 5px -1px black');
        $(this).find('.qRight > img').css('box-shadow', '-2px 2px 5px -1px black');
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.qLeft > img').css('box-shadow', '3px 5px 8px -2px black');
        $(this).find('.qRight > img').css('box-shadow', '-3px 5px 8px -2px black');
    });


<li style="float: left;" class="item">
    <div class="CardHeader">
        <h3>Appointment Calendar Book</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
         <img src="Assets/Calendar%20-%20Appointment%20Book4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="qContainer">
        <div class="qLeft">
            <img src="Assets/BlackGreenMinus.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="qCenter">1</div>
        <div class="qRight">
            <img src="Assets/BlackGreenPlus.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: could you include the html layout for the above code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is part of the solution. You should be able to figure out how to implement the rest:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {

    elements = this.querySelectorAll(".qLeft>img");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
      el.style.boxShadow = "2px 2px 5px -1px black";
    });

    // same for qRight
  });

  element.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: This is beautiful:-)

Answer (score 4):

Try using `css` `:hover`

```
.item .qLeft > img {
  /* default settings */
}

.item .qRight > img {
  /* default settings */
}

.item:hover .qLeft > img {
  /* do stuff */
}

.item:hover .qRight >img {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: I am wanting to do javascript - not css! :)

Comment: why not use pure css though?

Comment: @Bubbas, why? all you have shown is that you are adding a box-shadow style. Much more efficient to just do it in css than js.

Comment: im retarded. Yea - originally I wanted to do some JS stuff, but you're - at this point all im doing is changing style. LOL.  Glad I have your answer to point that out!